# MQL4 StringToDouble always returns zero

Tags: string, replace, mql4, metatrader4

The function `StringToDouble` always returns zero on passing a **variable** string.
Let me demonstrate ...

This is what I have so far.

```
string balance = "12.50USD";
// lets extract the double only from the string
int x = StringReplace(balance,"USD",""); // now we have a plain number
    
Print(balance); // "12.50"
double balance_only = StringToDouble(balance); 
Print(balance_only) ; // Zero? Why?
```

Well according to the documentation [here](https://docs.mql4.com/convert/strtodouble) and [here](https://docs.mql4.com/convert/stringtodouble)

This is supposed to work? Right? What am I missing?

I even tried to add empty strings on the sides to trick the function but still

```
double b = StringToDouble(StringConcatenate("",balance,"")); 
Print(b); // Zero , Why :(
```

What seems to be the problem here?

Comment: I think it must be something specific to your setup. Works exactly as it should for me (using your exact code). Just try using `Print(StringToDouble("12.50"));`

Comment: @PaulB My MetaEditor is 5.00 Build 2398 (5th May 2022), could this be an MQL4-specific error? I 've had it for past 2 days, still produces a Zero. Do we have a way in MQL4 to know the DataType of the object I am passing? Just to prove it is really a string at the point of passing it to StringToDouble?

Comment: @PaulB , when you passed it directly like that it works, but when you pass it as a result  variable from other String Manipulation functions ... it gets a zero.

Comment: Or it is because I am using an MT4 supplied from a broker?

Comment: Try installing another version of MetaTrader from somewhere else maybe? I can't see that you are doing anything wrong and it works on my setup (tried it on several different instances of MetaTrader 4 - all OK)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After installing and unistalling a couple of MT4 instances,

It was there all along,
For some reason I was also using **[StringSplit](https://docs.mql4.com/strings/stringsplit)** function i.e

```
StringSplit(extracted_balance_string," ", &results[]);
```

Instead of

```
StringSplit(extracted_balance_string,StringGetCharacter(" ",0), &results[]); // the space was a special character
```

I missed that, my bad :D